# extract dataframe value where two cells match

Tags: r

hi i have a dataframe "ko()":

```
a 10.5
b 12.2
c 12.9
d 13.7
```

and a dataframe "ri":

```
10 1
11 2
12 3
13 4
```

i make a new dataframe "lw" using

```
lw<-ko()[2]-ko()[2]%%1

10
12
12
13
```

how do i add a column to "lw" that has the value from ri[2] where lw and ri[1] match. the final dataframe would look like this:

```
10 1
12 3
12 3
13 4
```

its making me write extra text to submit ignore sorry thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
lw$V1 <- ri$V2[match(lw$V2, ri$V1)]
lw
#  V2 V1
#1 10  1
#2 12  3
#3 12  3
#4 13  4
```

**data**

```
ko <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(10.5, 12.2, 12.9, 13.7)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ri <- structure(list(V1 = 10:13, V2 = 1:4), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -4L))

lw <- ko[2]-ko[2]%%1
```